# Electron print horizontal space

Tags: laravel, printing, electron, nodes, thermal-printer

I want to print a bill using electron app with laravel and thermal printer. But when I print it inside electron app, it shows a blank space horizontally(red box)

[image: blank space horizontal]

But when I print it from browser (without electron) using ctrl+p key, it works fine

[image: correct ticket]

And this is how I do it

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote');
const options = {
    silent: true,
    printBackground: true,
    color: false,
    margins: {
        marginType: 'none'
    },
    landscape: false,
    pagesPerSheet: 1,
    collate: false,
    copies: 1,
    header: 'bill',
    footer: 'bill',
};

const win = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false
    }
});
const print = '{{ route('sale-invoice.bill', 'id') }}';
const url = print.replace('id', id);

win.loadURL(url);
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.webContents.print({}, (success, failureReason) => {
        if (!success) {
            showAlert('error', 'Error Occurred', failureReason);
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried to change the dpi, pageSize, & margins options but nothing is works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, My solution is：

```
    printWindow.webContents.print({
        silent: true,
        deviceName: "Microsoft Print to PDF",
        margins: {
            marginType: "none"
        },
        landscape: false,
        dpi: {
            horizontal: 600,
            vertical: 600
        },
        pageSize: "A4"
    }, () => {
    });
```

The value of dpi needs to view the properties of the local printer,
horizontal and vertical it is also possible to set only one of the values。

html css padding and margin set to 0.

I normally try the solution of not setting the dpi, I don't know if you have solved it, my friend.